# How do I prevent the browser from scrolling to the top on render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

How do I prevent the browser from scrolling to the top on render? This can be reproduced at https://www.gatsbyjs.org/ or https://reactjs.org/ by going to the website with a throttled network connection and scrolling down before the page renders.

This doesn't happen when JS is disabled. I believe this a Gatsby only problem.

Comment: maybe this may help history.scrollRestoration = "manual"

Comment: In my case I solved it by adding `gatsby-browser.js` with `exports.shouldUpdateScroll = () => false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up being a bug in Gatsby, which can be tracked at https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/6392#issuecomment-404444341.

One way around this is to disable scrolling before the component has been mounted and then reenabling it. This can be done with the following style change:

```
// styles.css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

// Component.js
componentDidMount () {
  document.body.style.overflow = 'auto'
}
```